# Node application crash if i use send or json

Tags: node.js, mongodb, web-services, crash, nodes

I am creating a IOS Application and in background we have used Node.js and Mongodb. I have create node application for creating user and send error and success response by jSon but if use `res.send` my node application will crash. 
I have tried to found issue but not get yet and positive response. Below my all code.

**`Controller :`**

```
const nodemailer    = require('nodemailer');
const passport      = require('passport');
const User          = require('../../models/User');





exports.ManuallySave = function(req,res)
{
  if(req.body.my_token !== '')
  {
    User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, (err, existingUser) => {
      if (existingUser) 
      {
        //res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.json({"status":'error',"msg":'Email address already exists.'});
      }
    });

    User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }, (err, existingUserName) => {
      if (existingUserName) 
      {
        res.send({"status":'error',"msg":'Username already exists.'});
      }
    });

    /* Save Action perform */
  }
  else 
  {
    res.send({"status":'error',"msg":'Token is not available.'});
  }

}
```

**`Console Error.`**

```
/var/www/node/MyApplication/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:98
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                  ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:344:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/var/www/node/MyApplication/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:718:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/var/www/node/MyApplication/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:163:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/var/www/node/MyApplication/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:249:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (/var/www/node/MyApplication/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:151:21)
    at /var/www/node/MyApplication/controllers/apis/userAppController.js:55:13
    at model.<anonymous> (/var/www/node/MyApplication/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1875:20)
    at next_ (/var/www/node/MyApplication/node_modules/hooks-fixed/hooks.js:89:34)
    at fnWrapper (/var/www/node/MyApplication/node_modules/hooks-fixed/hooks.js:186:18)
    at /var/www/node/MyApplication/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:226:5
    at /var/www/node/MyApplication/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:135:7
    at /var/www/node/MyApplication/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:504:5
    at /var/www/node/MyApplication/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:666:5
    at handleCallback (/var/www/node/MyApplication/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:96:12)
    at /var/www/node/MyApplication/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/unordered.js:473:9
    at handleCallback (/var/www/node/MyApplication/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:96:12)
    at resultHandler (/var/www/node/MyApplication/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/unordered.js:420:5)
    at /var/www/node/MyApplication/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/wireprotocol/2_4_support.js:544:17
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
```

I have used res.send and res.json both but in both condition my application will crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is thrown when you are trying to call methods on `res` when you already called `res.send`. There is no guarantee that it `res.send` only will be called once in your code, which there must be. The block

```
User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, (err, existingUser) => {
  if (existingUser) 
  {
    //res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.json({"status":'error',"msg":'Email address already exists.'});
  }
});

User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }, (err, existingUserName) => {
  if (existingUserName) 
  {
    res.send({"status":'error',"msg":'Username already exists.'});
  }
});
```

will call res.send twice if you already have a user with both that email address and that username. You will have to  do the other call within the first callback.

```
User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, (err, existingUser) => {
  if (existingUser) 
  {
    //res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.json({"status":'error',"msg":'Email address already exists.'});
  } else {
    checkUsername();
  }
});
function checkUsername() {
  User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }, (err, existingUserName) => {
    if (existingUserName) 
    {
      res.send({"status":'error',"msg":'Username already exists.'});
    } else {
      // save action
    }
  });
}
```

May I suggest you look into [promise chains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) to handle the inevitable upcoming callback nesting?

Comment: Thank your very much. I want 100 time (bow) you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should just use the or operator.

```
 User.findOne({ $or: [ {  email: req.body.email }, { username: req.body.username } ] }, (err, existingUser) => {
  if (existingUser) 
  {
    //res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.json({"status":'error',"msg":'Email address already exists.'});
  }
});
```

Than you just send one response.

Comment: The error message "Email address already exists." would not be accurate for both conditions.

Comment: You are right he could send beck Email or username already exists. But best solution is to use promises. what was suggested by @peternyc

Answer (score -1):

You're getting this error because your code allows for a res.send() after a res.json() has already been issues.

Your two validation checks both execute asynchronously, and if both validation conditions are met, then both res.json and res.send will be executed.

One solution is to embed the second check within the callback of the first like this:

```
const nodemailer    = require('nodemailer');
const passport      = require('passport');
const User          = require('../../models/User');

exports.ManuallySave = function(req,res){
    if(req.body.my_token !== ''){
        User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, (err, existingUser) => {
            if (existingUser) {
                res.json({"status":'error',"msg":'Email address already exists.'});
            } else {
                User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }, (err, existingUserName) => {
                    if (existingUserName) {
                        res.send({"status":'error',"msg":'Username already exists.'});
                    } else {
                        /* Save Action perform */
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    } else  {
        res.send({"status":'error',"msg":'Token is not available.'});
    }
}
```

I'd also recommend checking **err** in both of those callbacks and handling them.

Comment: This is to why some people hate js, don't write so much callbacks.

Comment: I don't disagree, but the OP already had the two callbacks.  So this was the closest solution to what he already had that would work.